# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}=\sup_k \left\{\frac{x_{n_k}}{n_k}\right\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be non-negative, increasing, and $\forall\ m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $x_{mn}\geq mx_n$. Show that there exists a subsequence $\left\{\frac{x_{n_k}}{n_k}\right\}$ of $\left\{\frac{x_n}{n}\right\}$ such that
> \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}=\sup_k \left\{\frac{x_{n_k}}{n_k}\right\}.
> \end{aligned}\end{equation*}

Choose $x_n=n^2$, we see both sides $=+\infty$. It seems OK. So I guess this problem is in a general limit concept.

We have $\frac{x_{mn}}{mn}\geq \frac{x_n}{n}$, for any $m,n$. How can this imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}$ exists? This is not similar to the problem like $x_{m+n}\leq x_m+x_n$...

Answer (score 1):

Define $y_n = \frac{x_n}n$.  Then we have $y_n > 0$ and $$n < m \implies ny_n \leq my_m \\ n \mid m \implies y_n \leq y_m$$

By a standard argument, there is some subsequence $y_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} y_{n_k} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} y_n$.

Now, fix $k$ and let $n \geq n_k$ be arbitrary.  Define $m = \lfloor n / n_k\rfloor$, so that $n_k m \leq n \leq n_k(m+1)$, showing
$$y_{n_k} \leq y_{n_km} \leq \frac{n}{n_km}y_n \leq \frac{m+1}my_n.$$

Letting $n\to \infty$ gives $$y_{n_k} \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor n/n_k\rfloor+1}{\lfloor n/n_k\rfloor}y_n = \liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n$$

but since this is true for every $k$, we also have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} y_n = \lim_{k\to\infty} y_{n_k} \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} y_n$$
showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$ exists.

---

Now that we know the limit exists, any subsequence will converge to it, and further, as $2^k \mid 2^{k+1}$ for every $k$, the subsequence $y_{2^k}$ is increasing.  It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = \sup\{y_{2^k} : k\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Comment: Just so I cover my bases, when I speak of limits existing and sequences converging, I am talking about existing and converging in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, not in $\mathbb{R}$.  If your lexicon doesn't agree with this use, then just make the appropriate substitutions as you're reading.